# Retrofit response 500 null message

Tags: java, android, kotlin, retrofit2, retrofit2.6

hello this is my code and why I cant get message like "The value is already exist" ?
why retrofit return null message in response with status 500?

```
    call.enqueue(object : Callback<Person> {
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<Person>, response: Response<Person>) {
                if (!response.isSuccessful) {
                    Log.e(ContentValues.TAG, "Code: " + response.message())
                    Toast.makeText(context, response.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                } else {
                    pr = response.body()!!
                    init(view)
                }
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<Person>, t: Throwable) {
                Log.e(ContentValues.TAG, "fauilure " + t.message)
                Toast.makeText(context, t.message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
        }
```

**this is my response from debugger (retrofit)**

Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=500, message=, url=http://192.168.1.239:8080/person/}

**and this is my server response (from postman)**

{"timestamp":"2021-02-21T12:50:35.222+00:00","status":500,"error":"Internal Server Error","message":"The value is already exist","path":"/person/"}

Answer (score 1):

You should use `response.errorBody()` method instead of `response.body()` to get error message.